# What happen to these S&P ETFs during 2016-2017?

Tags: united-states, etf

I'm taking a look at the historical data of these 2 S&P ETF, and I find something confusing.
Here are the 2 graphs:

1. [SPDR® Portfolio S&P 500 Growth ETF](https://money.usnews.com/funds/etfs/large-growth/spdr-portfolio-s-p-500-growth-etf/spyg)

[image]

2. [iShares Core S&P US Growth ETF](https://money.usnews.com/funds/etfs/large-growth/ishares-core-s-p-us-growth-etf/iusg)

[image]

These 2 ETFs have similar holdings, with top 10 holdings are the same. But one was crashing sometime on Oct 2017, whereas the other was sometime around July 2016.

My questions are:

1. What were the events that caused the ETF to drop so much during that time?
2. Why despite having the similar holding, the crash happened at different time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a ETF split, just like a stock split. You own more shares traded at lower price after the split.

Answer (score 2):

SPYG underwent a 1/4 stock split on 10/16/17

IUSG underwent a 1/2 stock split on 7/25/16